# How to read string after an option on bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract the string passed after an option:

eg.

```
./install -s service1 service2

if [ -z ${1} ] ; then
    echo "No option provided, defaulting to (-h)elp."
    echo
    option="-h"
else
    option=$1

fi
```

I would like to extract "service1 service2" from the argument list. How to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to look at [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Comment: `[ -z ${1} ]` is quite broken. Use `[ -z "$1" ]` -- the curly braces do nothing useful, the quotes are essential. If your script had been run with `./yourscript "nonempty -o 1 = 1"`, then you'd have `[ -z ${1} ]` returning true despite that value not being empty at all. And if your script had been invoked with `./yourscript '*'`, then the behavior of the test would depend on which filenames exist in the current working directory.

Comment: Similarly, even though `[ -z $1 ]` *looks* like it works, it does so for an entirely unintuitive reason: `[ -z ]`, which it parses to, is equivalent to `[ -n -z ]`, testing whether the string `"-z"` is empty or not and returning a truthy value if the string is **not** in fact empty.

Comment: BTW, see [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for advice on option-parsing that goes beyond `getopts`.

Comment: (BTW, as an important aside -- arguments aren't passed as a string, but as an *array* of strings. `service1` and `service2` are thus two completely separate strings -- if your program were run with `./install -s "Service One" "Service Two"`, then `$2` would be `Service One` and `$3` would be `Service Two`, and if you treated them as a single string (`Service One Service Two`) you'd lose the boundary info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shift` and the special variable `$@`:

```
option=$1
shift
echo "$@"
```

**Returns**:

```
service1 service2
```

As mentioned, if available `getopts` is a good option.